# Фильтрация строк в таблице(html)

Tags: html, jquery

Есть таблица вида

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Дата</th>
      <th>Значение1</th>
      <th>Значение2</th>
      <th>
        <?=$ item ?>
      </th>
      <?php } ?>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr id='tr1'>
    <td>
      2015-08
    </td>
    <td>
      1
    </td>
    <td>
      3
    </td>
  </tr>
  ......
</table>
```

"..."-там могут быть n записей.

Нужно по щелчку по кнопке скрыть/показать строки где значения равны 0.

сейчас делаю так(пытаюсь решение подобрать)

```js
 var tab = $('#tr1');
 var z = tab.find('td:contains("0")');
 $('#one').append(z);
```

Вывожу в див - чтобы можно было как-то обработать, в итоге удаляется обрабатываемая строка в таблице.

Как можно реализовать такой механизм фильтрации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел способ.

```js
for (i = 1; i < amount_row + 1; i++) {
  var tab = $('#tr' + i);
  var z = $("#tr" + i + " td:contains('0')");
  if (z.size() - 1 == amount_znach ) {
    $('#tr' + i).toggle();
  }
}
```

где amount_znach-количество столбцов со значениями,amount_row-количество строк в таблице.
Значения этих переменных мы должны знать заранее-в моем случае я получаю эти данные при выборке sql и передаю на вьюшку.

Проблема заключалась в том что в выборку по contains="0", попадали не только ячейки со значением 0, но и ячейка с датой(там тоже есть 0),это решилось с помощью вычитания из размерности полученной выборки 1.